# How to merge two different mysql select results in php with array_merge?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two different SELECT queries in php mysql.

I want to combine these two results into one array of objects. I don't want to use SQL UNION because there is some work to be done with the results before the merging.

There is php array_merge() function but when I try to use it, I get the following error:

> array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

The parameters are the results of a SQL select query.

```
$result1 = "";
$result2 = "";
$merged_results = "";

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT col1, col2 col3 from table1");
$stmt->execute();
$result1 = $stmt->get_result();

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT col1, col2 col3 from table2");
$stmt->execute();
$result2 = $stmt->get_result(); 

$merged_results = array_merge($result1,$result2);
```

My goal is an array of objects where every object represents a dataset from the mysql select, something like that:

> [{name:"Jonny",age:23},{name:"Bonny",age:25},{name:"Flower", age:21}]

so please how to merge these to results into one result of array of objects?

Comment: Get rid of these `$stmt->bind_param("sss",c1,c2,c3)` You're not binding anything and have no parameters.

Comment: Then you will need to fetch into an array http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: why should i get rid of this? its a prepared statement? please explain

Comment: No it's not.  You have no placeholders and are not binding any variables.  What the heck are `c1,c2,c3`?

Comment: Your problem is the SQL is incorrect.. All columns in the SQL should be comma separated. So this seams to  a simple typographical error question?

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Well no, they never fetched into arrays to merge.

Comment: "Well no, they never fetched into arrays to merge" Well yes without a correct valid query there isn't annything to fetch? right? @AbraCadaver

Comment: @RaymondNijland My point was; fix the typos and it still doesn't work, so NOT _a simple typographical error question_.

Comment: The point about no binding and no parameters is that your queries have no reason to use prepared statements at all.  Just run the queries without the extra overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am actually going to suggest that you just run a union query on MySQL directly:

```
SELECT col1, col2 col3 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2 col3 FROM table2;
```

This will avoid one extra round trip between PHP and MySQL.

```
$sql = "SELECT col1, col2 col3 FROM table1 UNION ALL ";
$sql .= "SELECT col1, col2 col3 FROM table2";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$resultset = $stmt->get_result();
```

If you also want to keep track of the source of each record, this too can be handled on MySQL using a computed column:

```
SELECT col1, col2 col3, 'table1' AS source FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2 col3, 'table2' FROM table2;
```

Answer (score 3):

get_result() is a mysqli result object, not your returned data.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

You would need to do something like this.

```
$merged_results = [];

$query = 'SELECT col1, col2 col3 from table1';
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $merged_results[] = $row;
}

$query = 'SELECT col1, col2 col3 from table2';
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $merged_results[] = $row;
}

var_dump($merged_results);
```

or you can do it in one query with union

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT col1, col2 col3 from table1 UNION SELECT col1, col2 col3 from table2");
$stmt->bind_param("sss",c1,c2,c3);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); 

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $merged_results[] = $row;
}

var_dump($merged_results);
```

Comment: Why the down vote? I think a user should give a reason for giving a down vote when they give it. I answered the user's question and gave a better solution to their problem.

Comment: minor typo: `$result2` vs `$result`, in second code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You have no placeholders and are not binding any variables, so I don't know why you're using `bind_param`.  Also, you will need to fetch the rows into an array which you are not doing:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT col1, col2, col3 from table1");
$stmt->execute();
$result1 = $stmt->get_result();
while($rows1[] = $result1->fetch_assoc());

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT col1, col2, col3 from table2");
$stmt->execute();
$result2 = $stmt->get_result();
while($rows2[] = $result2->fetch_assoc());

$merged_results = array_merge($rows1, $rows2);
```

There are other ways to go about this since you aren't actually binding any variables, but I used your code as you can extend it if you ever need to bind variables.

Comment: The SQL is incorrect.. All columns in the SQL should be comma separated you copy/paste from the topicstarters code without validating.

Comment: Minor simplification (when applicable): don't need `$rows2` and the `array_merge` - unless there is a reason to work with the two answers separately. Simply use `$merged_results` directly in *both* while loops: `while($merged_results[] = ...`.